# Growth factors of LU for diagonally dominant matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

The growth factor of LU decomposition is defined as $\rho = max_{i,j}|u_{ij}|/max_{i,j}|a_{ij}|$. Then how can I prove that if A is diagonally dominant (row or column), then $\rho \le 2$? I've tried proving by induction but failed.